# Reduction for positive number sorting task to prove nlogn complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, reduction

As it is proven, comparison based sorting has complexity `T(n)=nlogn`. So if we have array of positive integers (not specific one-so that `counting` or `radix` sorts cannot be applied) how to determine appropriate reduction from `Sort` to `SortPositiveNumbers` (for example) in order to prove that there is polynomial and correct transformation and `SortPositiveNumbers` has also lower bound of `nlogn` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: VtC too broad. Maybe CS.SE will help you with your homework...

Comment: This is not a homework. But a task for exam preparation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reduce Sort to SortPositiveNumbers using the following pseudo-code:

```
Sort(A[1..n])
   B[1..n]
   p <- n+1
   s <- 0
   for k <- 1 to n
       if A[k] > 0
          p <- p-1
          B[p] <- A[k]
       else if A[k] < 0
          s <- s+1
          B[s] <- -A[k]

   SortPositiveNumbers(B[1...s])
   SortPositiveNumbers(B[p...n])

   for k <- 1 to s
       A[k] <- -B[s+1-k]
   for k <- s+1 to p-1
      A[k] <- 0
   for k <-p to n
      A[k] <- B[k]
```

Here the reduction is linear (2n), so it is polynomial and it is correct because it uses SortPositiveNumbers to sort only positive numbers from A( negatives are converted into positive) and finally the reduction again converts positive into negative and adds them into the needed index of the sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's a assume that you can sort positive numbers with complexity `C' < nlogn`. Then I can sort arbitrary arrays by spliting them into positive and negative (O(N)) converting the negatives into positives (O(N)) sorting the two arrays (O(C'), times 2 but it doesn't matter for complexity), reverse the negative array O(N) and concatenating the two arrays (O(N)). So even overall the complexity is O(N + C') (that is maximum between O(N) and O(C')). This is lower than `nlogn` which you have proven to be minimum complexity for sorting arbitrary arrays. This is a contradiction, so it follows that the initial assumptions (the only assumption we've made) is wrong. That is there's co algorithm with a complexity less than nlogn for sorting positive numbers.